# how to change text to input field onclick in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change the `Text` to `input` field when clicking on edit button. The Text is inside `map` function,
The Code that I have worked is mentioned below

```
function test() {
  const [img, setImg] = useState(false)

  let data = {
    {  
      id: 1,
      name: 'test 1'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'test 2'
    }
  }

return (
  <>
    {data.map(e => {
      return (
        {img ? (
          <input placeholder={e.name} />
        ) : (
          <div>
            <p>{e.name}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setImg(true)}>edit</button>
          </div>
        )}
      )
    })}
  </>
)
```

In this code if i click on edit button, it actually shows input in all name, rather than which i click.
i want to edit only one name, for example, if i want to edit name `test 1`, i dont want the input to show on `test 2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this would work -

```
function test() {
  const [img, setImg] = useState(-1)

  let data = {
    {  
      id: 1,
      name: 'test 1'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'test 2'
    }
  }

return (
  <>
    {data.map((e, idx) => {
      return (
        {img==idx ? (
          <input placeholder={e.name} style={{display: idEdit == e.id ? 'block' : 'none'}}/> //<== Conditionaly to appear or not
        ) : (
          <div>
            <p>{e.name}</p>
            <button onClick={() => {
               setImg(idx)
              } 
             }>edit</button>
          </div>
        )}
      )
    })}
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a state when you click edit button, then use this state to conditionally show of input you want:

```
function test() {
  const [img, setImg] = useState(false)
  const [idEdit, setIdEdit] = useState(null); //<== Create this state

  let data = {
    {  
      id: 1,
      name: 'test 1'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'test 2'
    }
  }

return (
  <>
    {data.map(e => {
      return (
        {img ? (
          <input placeholder={e.name} style={{display: idEdit == e.id ? 'block' : 'none'}}/> //<== Conditionaly to appear or not
        ) : (
          <div>
            <p>{e.name}</p>
            <button onClick={() => {
               setImg(true)
               setIdEdit(e.id) //<== set idEdit state here
              } 
             }>edit</button>
          </div>
        )}
      )
    })}
  </>
)
```

Comment: it actually works, But has a flaw, The `text` in all other also gets hidden because of `img` `useState`

Comment: What you can do is maintain the `img` state variable as a number instead of a boolean. The default value will be -1. Inside the onClick function set the value to be the index that is required to be shown as an input tag. (Edit: Refer to my answer for better understanding)

Answer (score 0):

here is if you are using an API to update your profile
I used the above answers and updated them to suite API
I used axios to fetch and update the data.
hope it helps
I am using react.js and tailwind:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React from 'react'
import {useEffect} from 'react'
import { useState} from 'react'

function Ex() {

const [img, setImg] = useState(false)
const [idEdit, setIdEdit] = useState(null);
const [data, setData] = useState({})

function data() {
axios.get(`api/${id)}`)
  .then((res) => {
    setData(res.data)
  })
}

useEffect(() => {
 data()
}, [])

function update() {
axios.put(`api/${data.id}`, {
  name: data.name,
  email: data.email
 })
setImg(false)
}

const save = (e) => {
setData({ ...data,
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value
})
}

return ( 
<div className = 'flex justify-center items-center w-screen h-screen' > 
 {img?
  <div className = 'grid grid-cols-1 gap-5   bg-black p-10  ' >
  <input className = 'rounded-xl border p-2'onChange = {save}
    name = 'name'
    value = { data.name}
    style = {{display: idEdit == data.id ? 'block' : 'none' }}/>  
  <input className = 'rounded-xl border p-2' onChange = {save}
  name = 'email'
  value = {data.email}style = {{display: idEdit == data.id ? 
  'block':'none'}}/> 
  <button onClick = {(() => update())}
  className = 'bg-amber-900 rounded-xl p-1 text-white' > Update </button> 
  </div>
   :
   <div className = 'grid text-white grid-cols-1 gap-5 bg-black p-10 
     rounded-xl'>
    <p className = 'text-xl' > Name: {data.name} < /p>
    <p className = 'text-xl' > Email: {data.email} < /p>
    < button className = 'bg-amber-900 mt-4 rounded-xl p-1  text-white'
    onClick = {() => {setImg(true) setIdEdit(data.id) }}> Edit < /button>
    </div>} 
   </div>
     )}

  export default Ex
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.